# casting a pointer to struct for qsort's compare

Tags: c, pointers, casting, qsort

So I'm using qsort() in c and my compare function usually consist of creating a pointer of the correct type and assigning it the value from the arguments. is it possible to just cast the pointer from the arguments without creating a new one?
if so, what am i doing wrong?

```
struct date_t{
    int time;
    int dob;
};

/* the old working function
int cmpfunc (const void * one, const void * two) {
    struct date_t *itemtwo=two;
    struct date_t *itemone=one;
return itemone->time-itemtwo->time;
}
*/

int cmpfunc (const void * one, const void * two) {
    return (struct date_t*)(one)->time - (struct date_t*)two->time;
}
```

i'm getting :

```
main.c:17:30: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
  return (struct date_t*)(one)->time - (struct date_t*)two->time;
                          ^~
main.c:17:30: error: request for member 'time' in something not a structure or union
```

EDIT:

i got it to compile with

```
int cmpfunc (struct date_t *one, struct date_t *two) {
    return one->time - two->time;
}
```

but still, how would i do it with casts?

Comment: Cast it like this: `((struct date_t*)one)->time`. Mind the operator precedence.

Comment: `((struct date_t*)one)->time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [handy precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the cast operation has a lower precedence than the structure member access operator `->`. So when doing `(struct date_t*)(one)->time`, first the member `time` is accessed (and failed, as `one` is a `void*` and has no such a member). And only then the cast is performed on the result. Instead you should force the precedence by using parentheses in appropriate places like:

```
... ((struct date_t*)one)->time ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The type cast operator `()` has lower precedence than the pointer-to-member operator `->`.  So this:

```
(struct date_t*)(one)->time
```

Is the same as this:

```
(struct date_t*)((one)->time)
```

You need to parenthesize what is casted, then you can dereference the pointer.

```
int cmpfunc (const void * one, const void * two) {
    return ((const struct date_t*)(one))->time - ((const struct date_t*)two)->time;
}
```

Also note that the casted pointers are `const` to be consistent with the original pointers.